# (ELK) logstash grok for SBR accounting log

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, logstash-grok, elastic-stack

How can I map field to the message on SBR accounting log that has a format as followed example.

```
"Date","Time","RAS-Client","Record-Type","Full-Name","Auth-Type","User-Name","Framed-IP-Address","Calling-Station-ID","Called-Station-ID","Framed-Interface-Id","Delegated-IPv6-Prefix","NAS-Identifier","NAS-IP-Address","NAS-Port","NAS-Port-Type","NAS-Port-ID","Filter-ID","Acct-Termination-Cause","Acct-Session-Id","Acct-Session-Time","Acct-Status-Type","Acct-Delay-Time","Acct-Input-Octets","Acct-Output-Octets","Acct-Authentic","Acct-Input-Packets","Acct-Output-Packets","Acct-Multi-Session-Id","Acct-Input-Gigawords","Acct-Output-Gigawords","Event-Timestamp","Service-Type","Framed-Protocol","Connect-Info","Idle-Timeout","Session-Timeout","HW-Connect-ID","HW-Domain-Name"
```

There are both "xxx" and empty field separated with comma (,).

For example,

"03/07/2016","17:00:00","abc",,,"xyz",......

My configuration .yml file filter are like this.

```
filter {
  mutate {
    # replace all comma with space
    gsub => [ "message", ",", " " ]
  }
  grok {
    match => [ "message", "(%{DATE:date})? (%{TIME:time})? (%{WORD:bras})? (%{WORD:recordtype})? (%{WORD:fullname})? (%{WORD:authtype})? (%{WORD:username})? (%{IP:ipaddress})? (%{MAC:callingstationid})? (%{MAC:calledstationid})? %{GREEDYDATA:message}" ]
  }
}
```

But looks like not working now.

PS. I'm just a beginner in ELK stack, and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: What's not working exactly ? You might want to take a look at this : https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ . Also, I'm not convinced by your ```gsub``` I'd just integrate the ```,``` in the grok pattern

Comment: @maximede Thanks for your answer. It help me a lot. I have used the grokdebug and it's working fine with this code. '("%{DATE:date}")?,("%{TIME:time}")?,("%{DATA:rasclient}")?,.....' but when I use it on my .yml file and run with logstash, it will show the error. I think it's because of the "," and "()? or double quote. I would like to ask you more about how to use it in the file. I have ever seen some url use "\" to solve this but I'm not sure. Could you provide me an example. Really appreciate your help.